# php function redeclaration issue in an old project

Tags: php

I took up a very old project to do some minor changes and encountered this type of code in it

file 1.php

```
function PageContent() {
   echo "This is the page content";
   }
```

file 2.php

```
function PageContent() {
   echo "Some other content";
   }
```

And this is in multiple files. The project is very big to dig everything.
When I run the code I get

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare PageContent() (previously declared .....

This is in multiple places. I don't want to go over all application and change everything as I want only to run and do a minor change.

Is this a php version issue or some kind of php setting or some other issue?

Comment: No its not a php version issue, no its not some kind of php settings or some other issue. If you want to fix it you will have to go through it and change it.

Comment: This is a "bad programming" issue and PHP reacts as it should ([and always has](https://3v4l.org/N7Yt9)). However, as of PHP7 many errors become catchable, see [the manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.errors.php7.php) for more information (but it seems, this specific fatal error cannot be caught)

Comment: You have to change the application. You cannot redeclare functions, it's exactly how it should be.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot redeclare functions in PHP, you only can override them, check http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php